In Next Image component set height to 100px and width to auto
I'm building a landing page using Next JS. For logo I'm making use Image component and I want logo to be 100px tall and width should be auto calculated. But I'm not able to get this right in next js.
As everyone know we need to define both height and width for Image component and it should be a integer.
If I set height to 100 and width to 100 it solve my problem but I get following error in the console
Image has either width or height modified, but not the other. If you use CSS to change the size of your image, also include the styles 'width: "auto"' or 'height: "auto"' to maintain the aspect ratio.

Accoding to warning if I set a inline style of width to auto Image occupies entire size of the viewport. What's the solution?
<Image
  width={100}
  height={100}
  alt='Logo'
  style={{ width: 'auto' }}
  className='hidden cursor-pointer md:block'
  src='/images/logo.svg'
/>

